# How to ask for input to initialize multiple structs at one time

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
struct Student {
    string name;
    int CWID;
    float GPA;
};
```

Now, I have an array of 5 Students:

```
Student* s = new Student[5];
```

Now I want to initialize them using console input in this form:

```
John    5012356   3.5
Mike    5012432   3.6
Ryan    5013521   3.3
Mary    5012784   4.0
Harry   5012695   3.1
```

My trivial logic is:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "\n\nPlease enter Student " << (i + 1) << "'s details (Name, CWID, GPA): ";
        cin >> s[i].name >> s[i].CWID >> s[i].GPA;
 }
```

Instead of asking the 5 inputs separately, how can I take them all at once?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in separately vs. all at once except for the prompts. By the way, if you know the size of the array, use an array (or `std::array` if you can). If you don't, use `std::vector`. Don't use `new[]`.

Comment: How about when reading the input from a file?

Comment: How about searching StackOverflow for answers in reading data from a file?  Try this:  ["stackoverflow c++ read file structure"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+structure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ Reading File into a Structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200784/c-reading-file-into-a-structure-array-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of asking the 5 inputs separately, how can I take them all at once?

Using the console for entering input is so old school.

1. Put the data in a file.
2. Get rid of the prompts for user input in your program.
3. Use the file as the source of your input.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> s[i].name >> s[i].CWID >> s[i].GPA;
 }
```

Usage:

```
 ./program < input.txt
```

Comment: Please explain the complete code like ifsteam and all.

Comment: @B-Mac, there is no `ifstream` involved in this. The contents of `input.txt` can be read from `cin` when used like I've shown.

Comment: @B-Mac The key is understanding that the `<` operator on the commandline is the [redirection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection) operator. Specifically, redirection of the contents of `input.txt` to the `stdin` of `./program`.

Comment: @RSahu I'd say this is a fine method so long as the constraints of having to be able to make the file before executing the program and only being able to input the file once are valid. And that there is no input requested before the contents of the file need to be parsed.

Comment: @aruisdante, any input required by the program can be put in a file. You can have multiple files that contain different data sets. Also, you avoid the work of entering the numbers repeatedly when you are testing and debugging your code.

Comment: @RSahu Sure. I meant more that the input can be predicted before hand. For example, if this is an interactive terminal program for managing student data, where only one possible input option is "enter new students" or some such, then this approach might not be the best. Sure, you could add command line options to make the program always operate as a 'oneshot' like, say, git. But even if the design could be accommodating of such a mode of operation, the *userbase* of the program (presumably teachers or admin. assistants) might not be.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `cout` and place it outside the loop.

```
cout << "\n\nPlease enter Students' details (Name, CWID, GPA): \n";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> s[i].name >> s[i].CWID >> s[i].GPA;
}
```

There is nothing different actually; it's just the way you see things. You might wanna use `files` instead, though. It might save you some time if you always need a certain set of values.

Comment: I know `cin >>` skips leading whitespace, but does it also skip line breaks? If not, I would use `std::getline()` on each loop iteration, with a `std::istringstream` to stream the line content into the current struct.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Line breaks are considered whitespace. For example, `std::isspace('\n') != 0`